# VPN and local web access

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm new to VPN and I wanted to know more. I apologize if this question does not make sense.

Does having VPN between two or more offices mean that you can (from any office) access the local SMB share of the main office, local website etc?

For example, if I usually access a certain web server in the main office via http://192.168.X.XX/application, will I be able to access the same thing (using that address) through VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not automatically. If you want to open your samba share to other vpn users, you will still have to open the vpn ip range (e. g. 10.2.0.x) manually.